# How to create a cctv monitoring ML solution to classify images?

Tags: classification, data-stream-mining

I have a cctv that records video of products that move over a factory line.

I want to stream the cctv into a ML solution that will classify the products, and if it detects that it is a certain type then send an email to manager.

Is this an image or video classification problem?

Using OpenCV (python) I can access the cctv video stream. What is recommended library to train and perform the ML image/video classification?

Comment: whatever you want, TF maybe is more production ready since it has a whole ecosystem around it for deploying and managing ML pipelines...

Answer (score 2):

Video classification is nothing but when we send each frame of video which is a image and classify it individually and independently to predict the largest probable outcome.

For the presented use case it seems that you want the result to be real time then we need to treat it as video classification problem.

What we can do is that create a dataset of type of products in the factory or a open source dataset. Train Resnet model on this dataset. Run the trained model on each grabbed frame of the video and then average all the individual probabilities to get the final probabilities vector. This is a single frame cnn architecture for video classification and would work best for this use case and ther

Refer: [Video Classification](https://learnopencv.com/introduction-to-video-classification-and-human-activity-recognition/) ,
[Video classification Tutorial](https://pyimagesearch.com/2019/07/15/video-classification-with-keras-and-deep-learning/)

Comment: What does `Resnet` model mean?

Comment: Resnet is a Residual Network Model https://keras.io/api/applications/resnet/

Comment: What is the difference between using TensorFlow object detection (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/inference_tf2_colab.ipynb) vs keras (https://pyimagesearch.com/2019/07/15/video-classification-with-keras-and-deep-learning/)?

Comment: I think that the keras example you have shared is more appropriate to train/classify video of single activity like jumping, kicking. Where as the TensorFlow object detection is more suitable in my scenario of training based on images and then classifying/detecting objects that are passing on a production line (frame by frame). Correct?

Comment: The tensorflow one is a image classification one and keras one is more of video classification. With tensorflow you are using only one frame to predict a probability whereas in keras we are using multiple frames to predict the object. If there is a fixed gap in products on production line then image classification would be a better choice.

Comment: `With tensorflow you are using only one frame to predict a probability` - correct but if I use it in while loop of opencv video capture then it will perform frame by frame object detection. `If there is a fixed gap in products on production line then image classification would be a better choice.` - even if there is no gap then the TensorFlow object detection can detect multiple objects in the same frame. `Question`: Can keras approach work if more than 1 object comes in the frame/video?

Comment: Resnet has low latency and is light weight . So you should train over resnet.